# How to write many arguments to the output file from reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a text file as below

```
250788965731,20090906,200937,200909,621,SUNDAY,WEEKEND,ON-NET,MORNING,OUTGOING,VOICE,25078,PAY_AS_YOU_GO_PER_SECOND_PSB,SUCCESSFUL-RELEASEDBYSERVICE,5,0,1,6.25,635-10-104-40163.
```

I'm just a beginner in hadoop.I faced the following problem.

How do i print the entire line in my output file? As far as i know only A key & A Value can be written to the output file. How to write this entire line with many arguments in my output file. Or how do i write atleast a few arguments of it in a output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TextOutputFormat and write the line as a Text writable as the key.  Make the value null

```
context.write( new Text("your output line") , null);
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Gerken. I got the output i wanted.